# How to get PostgreSQL DB info in Python3 with psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am using `psycopg2` to do PostgreSQL queries from Python3. I got several results without any problem. However, I cannot get the name, codification and owner of databases. This is my code:

```
dbname = 'my_database'

query_get_db_data = (
   'SELECT d.datname, d.datctype, '
   'pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as owner '
   'FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d '
   'WHERE d.datname = (%s);'
)

result = conn.cursor.execute(query_get_db_data, (dbname, ))
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry for my mistake, I was getting None for other reason, the real error is I am getting this message:

> syntax error at or near "'my_database'" LINE 4: WHERE d.datname =
>   ('my_new_database')

I tried to remove the parenthesis but then the problem is the quotes. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parenthesis from around the *%s*. The *paren* syntax is for use with `IN` as opposed to `=`.

Also, I would recommend you take advantage of *Python*'s built-in multiline strings, so you don't have to add all those single quotes on every line.

i.e.

```
query_get_db_data = """
   SELECT d.datname, d.datctype,
   pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as owner
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
   WHERE d.datname = %s"""

result = conn.cursor.execute(query_get_db_data, (dbname, ))
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed that you said you tried removing the parens, and then the quotes were an issue. That doesn't seem like it should be a problem. What was the error you got when you removed the quotes? When I try to run that query (against a *Postgres 9.0* server), it works OK when I remove the parens. This is in *psql*, however. It's possible I suppose there is a *Python 3.x* aspect to this, although I can't think of anything offhand that would be different in 3.x vs. 2.x in this case. (Unless perhaps you have DB names that have extended ASCII characters in them?)